# Mips Assembly Language Saving Bytes in .data

Tags: byte, mips

Hello Im pretty new to Mips and I'm trying to save three 8-bit value and there hex value while including the 0X prefix to make sure they are read as hexadecimal. I made a table of three values I would like to store.

[Table of Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yASqX.png)

I would like these values to be stored in the .data section, I'm aware I need to use .byte to store them but can't figure out how to store multiple values. I later need to loop through each value. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate them by commas:

```
.data
foo: byte 0x0, 0x1, 0x2
```

Note that the `0x` prefix is completely unnecessary. `0, 1, 2` would give you exactly the same values. They are just collections of bits, and whether you want to present them to the user as a base10 string or a base16 string at some point is irrelevant.